# building Mac OS apps with Flash

Tags: macos, flash, air, app-store, flash-cs6

I thought this should be straight forward to create an .app package using flash cs6. But I'm experiencing strange problems while building .app or .pkg: adt crashes with 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Contents of my jvm.ini:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Xmx1024m
```

The project I'm trying to compile is real simple with 2 moving images on the stage. The same project compiles and works great on Android and iOS devices.
I'm using AIR 3.7

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried increasing -Xmx? It's pretty big already, but that's the usual solution and you haven't stated if you did that or not.

Comment: yep, any value higher than 1024 prevents flash from start reporting invalid Java configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrading to Flash CC/AIR SDK 3.9 fixed the problem.